# 404 file not found ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kuberentes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: posts.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /posts/create
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: posts-clusterip-srv
                port:
                  number: 4000
          - path: /posts
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: query-srv
                port:
                  number: 4002
          - path: /posts/?(.*)/comments
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: comments-srv
                port:
                  number: 4001
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

when I try to acces posts.com on localhost getting 404, looks regular expresssion ?(.*) is not working, but able to access  posts.com/posts.

I think I need to convert Regular Expression 2 https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax, need help to convert ?(.*) to RE2, thank you

Comment: sorry my mistake the issue was typo in 'kuberentes' nginx.ingress.kuberentes.io/use-regex: 'true'.
it should be nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'

Comment: Is your issue resolved? if so can you post the Fix as the answer and accept it for the better community visibility.

Comment: yes, change to nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'